# iTunes Music track view url open

Tags: ios, itunes

I am getting iTunes Track view url from  this API `http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/wsSearch?term=hello&entity=musicTrack&&limit=10`

```
"trackViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/hello/id405926181?i=405926184&uo=4"
```

When I am trying to load track view URL using below code I am getting Safari Can't open page. I logged string of URL it's absolutely fine and it's opening in browser of my Mac also.

```
NSString *trackViewUrl =[music objectForKey:@"trackViewURL"];
    NSLog(@"iTunes URL : %@",trackViewUrl);
    NSURL *appstoreURL = [NSURL URLWithString:trackViewUrl];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appstoreURL];
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your NSLog() statement should be outputting `iTunes URL : (null)`.

```
NSLog(@"iTunes URL : %@",trackViewUrl);
```

You're attempting to access the dictionary's object for the `trackViewURL` key, but it looks like it should be `trackViewUrl`, with the "r" and the "l" lowercase. Try again after correcting the case of these characters.

**EDIT:** That possible typo aside, I've just tested your code with corrected capitalization, and it works fine. It is important to note however that this will not work on the simulator. You need to use it on a real device that actually has the iTunes app installed.